# Is there a way to obtain integer values when using class_weight parameter in DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I am using a DecisionTreeClassifier() for an imbalanced dataset with class_weight='balanced' parameter.

When plotting the tree, the nodes have floats in the 'value' attribute, which I guess it has something to do with the weights. My question is: is here is a way to turn those values in the real integer numbers (number of records for each class)? Or at least that they can sum up to the number of samples on that node?

[image: Tree with float values in nodes]

I have seen (in other posts) that in RandomForest you can set the 'bootstrap' parameter to change this, I don't know if is the same as in here, but there is no bootstrap parameter in the class DecisionTree.

Comment: Can you show your code to train and plot the tree? And maybe some data if you can.

Comment: Sure @Mattravel, this is the code:
`dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini', max_depth=5, min_samples_leaf=5, min_samples_split=10, random_state=0, class_weight='balanced').fit(X,y)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use class_weight='balanced' in [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)(), the values will indeed appear weighted (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18943)).

What you can do is use proportion=True in [plot_tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html), this will at least give you the unweighted proportion percentage.

Comment: That will work for now, thank you! However, I saw there is an issue open in the Sklearn [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18943) where someone is interested in the same as me.